# Question related to N-th cyclotomic polynomial, principal N-th root of unity and residue class of X

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am struggling to understand a couple of statements in a cryptography-related paper. I think I lack some maths background. Can you help me understand it ?

Here are the statements:

> We consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(\Phi_m(X))$, where $\Phi_m(X)$ is the $m$-th cyclotomic polynomial. Suppose the factorization of $\Phi_m(x) \bmod p^r$ for a prime power $p^r$ is $\Phi_m(X)=F_1(X)...F_k(X)$, where each $F_i$ has the same degree $d$. 
> We define $E=\mathbb{Z}[X]/(p^r, F_1(X))$ and let $\zeta$ be the residue class of $X$ in $E$, which is a principal $m$-th root of unity, so that $E=\mathbb{Z}/(p^r)[\zeta]$.....

(extracted from Bootstrapping for HElib, Halevi and Shoup, 2015).

The sentence that I don't understand is the last one. How come $\zeta$ can be the residue class of $X$ in $E$ and why is it a $m$-th root of unity ??

Besides, I don't understand the notation $E=\mathbb{Z}/(p^r)[\zeta]$.

Any explanation would be helful.
Many thanks.

Comment: Basically the residue class of $X$ is a zero of $F_1(X)$ in the ring $E$. Because $F_1(X)$ is a factor of the cyclotomic polynomial, we can call any of its zeros $\zeta$ without creating too much confusion :-).

Comment: The mechanism of extending a commutative ring $R$ by "creating" a zero of a monic polynomial $f(X)$ works the same way in general. We consider the bigger ring $S=R[X]/(f(X))$. The coset $x+(f(X))$ is then A) an element of $S$, B) a zero of $f(X)$, and C) we can think of $R$ as a subring of $S$ by identifying elements of $R$ with the cosets of the constant polynomials. All this is "bread & butter" in courses on basic structures of abstract algebra. It is challenging to write textbooks for crypto students, because they don't always have enough algebra. Looks like you are doing ok though!

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
However, I am still confused by some of your terms (yes I am a crypto student!). 
I understood statements (A) and (C), but not (B).
Why $x+(f(X))$ is a zero of $f(X)$?

Comment: You also mentionned that the "residue class of $X$ is zero of $F_1(X)$ in the ring $E$", but I cannot understand why... 

I hope you can explain to me! @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: I got it!
Let $d=deg(f(X))$ such that $f(X)=\sum^{d}_{i=0} a_i\cdot X^i$. Then $f(x + f(x))=\sum_{i=0}^d a_i \cdot (x + f(x))^i =  \sum_{i=0}^d a_i \cdot  (x^i + \alpha_i(x)\cdot f(x)) = \sum_{i=0}^d a_i x^i + f(x)\cdot \sum_{i=0}^d a_i \cdot  \alpha_i(x) = f(x) + f(x)\cdot \beta (x) = 0 + \gamma (x)\cdot f(x)$. The second equality is due to the binomial expansion. $\alpha_i$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ being polynomial in $R[X]$ resulting from this expansion.

 So it means that the residue class of $X$ is a zero of $f(X)$. QED...

Could someone please check my answer to close the topic.